# How to get ASUS UEFI BIOS EZ Mode utility on my Asus laptop?

Tags: motherboard, uefi, asus-laptop

I have asus laptop with the following specs:

```
Manufacturer    ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
Model   K53SC (CPU 1)
Version 1.0
Chipset Vendor  IntelBIOS
Brand   American Megatrends Inc.
Version K53SC.208
Chipset Model   Sandy Bridge

BIOS
Brand   American Megatrends Inc.
Version K53SC.208

Operating System
    MS Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
```

In the UEFI settings I have enabled 'UEFI' but im not unable to see the graphical interface of UEFI.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing something, having a UEFI BIOS does not necessarily mean that you have a graphical BIOS interface. You will probably only get that on fancy desktop boards.

For more information on what UEFI really is, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) out.